# Calculate percent from custom int

Tags: c#, math, calculator

I'm pretty bad at maths and I'm hoping someone can help me with this or explain how it works. I am trying to program a custom progressbar where the location should just change where location x = 1 //0% and location x= 363 //100%. y is always 0

Here is the method I am trying to implement

```
private void SetProgressValue(int value)
        {
            // value min = 0;
            // value max = 100;

            //Location 1, 0 = 0%
            //Location 363, 0 = 100%

            Point newLocation;
            int result = value * 100 / 363;
            newLocation = new Point(result, 0);
            spanProgress.Location = new Point(newLocation.X, newLocation.Y);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is probably that you use ints to calculate fractions.

Suggestion:

```
float result = (value / 100.0) * 363;
```

Comment: or `float result = (value / 100m) * 363m;` for [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types)